# unable to locate package libfaac-dev

Tags: 14.04, opencv

I'm trying with installing-`opencv-2-4-9`-in-ubuntu-14-04 in a tutorial..

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev libjpeg-dev libtiff4-dev libjasper-dev libopenexr-dev cmake python-dev python-numpy python-tk libtbb-dev libeigen3-dev yasm libfaac-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libqt4-dev libqt4-opengl-dev sphinx-common texlive-latex-extra libv4l-dev libdc1394-22-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev default-jdk ant libvtk5-qt4-dev
```

the output is :

```
reading packages lists Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information Done
E: unable to locate package libfaac-dev
```

Is it important to locate/install `libfaac-dev` in order to have successful installation, and if it is, what should I do now?

Answer (score 5):

Edit this file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Add `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main multiverse` to bottom.

Then `apt-get update`

[Reference Installation](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/trusty/multiverse/l/libfaac-dev/install/index.html)

Comment: This is the right answer for those who are using AWS EC2

Answer (score 4):

`libfaac-dev` is available from multiverse [repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libfaac-dev), so you have to enable multiverse repository in your sources.

To do that, open Software center, navigate to the "Ubuntu software" tab at the top, select (check) multiverse (4th check box). Now, click on 'Close' and then 'Reload' to update your package list.

Now you can go ahead with the installation.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't see how to accomplish the 'Reload' part of the instructions.  I looked everywhere in the Software center, but could find no option to 'Reload'.   Also, I had to go to "Edit" and then "Software Sources" to get to the "Software and Update" tab you show above.  How does one 'Reload'??

Comment: Hit close and a pop up will appear. Click reload there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings > Software and Updates > Ubuntu Software. Then check the multiverse option. Basically what [Ron](https://askubuntu.com/users/402004/ron) said, but in a different location.